# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: seaborn

how to solve 'str' object has no attribute 'get' error while trying to execute this code:

sns.countplot(x='Survived', data='train')

I have already successfully imported seaborn as sns and read the data with: train = pandas.csv_read()

Comment: Have a look at the `data` parameter you are passing to `sns.countplot` and ask yourself the question: "am I passing a variable called `train` or the string `'train'`?"

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't realised i've put a ' ' on train.